# For two elliptic curves $E_1,E_2$, what is the structure of $Hom(E_1,E_2)$ as a left/right module over the endomorphism rings of $E_1,E_2$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Given two elliptic curves - lets say over $\mathbb{C}$ for simplicity, the group
$$Hom(E_1,E_2)$$
is naturally an $(End(E_2),End(E_1))$-bimodule.

What is the structure of this bimodule?

Considered as a module under one of $End(E_1), End(E_2)$, is it cyclic?

Given a fixed integer $n > 1$, is it possible to classify the isogenies $E_1\rightarrow E_2$ of degree $n$ up to automorphisms of the source or target?

References would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that for almost all $E_1$ both of these endomorphism algebras are just $\mathbb{Z}$? So you're essentially asking about the case when $E_1$ and $E_2$ are CM curves with CM by the same quadratic imaginary field?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yep! I'm aware. I'm sure the answer to this question must be written down somewhere in some book, I just don't know where...